# Prove $a+b+c \geq \frac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2}$ for $a,b,c \in [0, \frac32]$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c \in \left[0;\frac{3}{2}\right]$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$. Prove that
> $$a+b+c \geq \dfrac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2}.$$

**Source**: This is a math problem that my teacher gave me $3$ months ago (the submission deadline has expired). My teacher wrote a book and sent me to test the difficulty of the problem.

**My attempt**: I have converted $a$ to $b,c$, used to trigonometric conversion, but all failed.

**Related problem** (the same source, with the same conditions): https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2975620p26673082

Please give me a suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: Have you thought about or tried Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I also tried. Since $a,b,c \in [0;\frac{3}{2}]$ the Lagrange multipliers method cannot find the minimum!

Comment: Actually what about writing Newton's identity ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Comment: It's advisable to write out your attempts in some detail rather than just mentioning in a word or two, perhaps someone could correct it.  Lagrange multipliers or a suitable trigonometric  substitution are both promising methods.  Just because there is an interval bound doesn't mean you can't use them - it just means the extrema could also be on the boundary rather than just internal points.

Comment: Do you mean $\left[0,\dfrac32\right]$?

Comment: @youthdoo My teacher wrote a book and sent me to test the difficulty of the problem

Comment: See if you can improve this. From the given condition, $a\left(a-\dfrac32\right)\le0$, so $\displaystyle\sum a^2\le\frac32\sum a$. Then$$\frac 32\sum a+\left(\frac{a+b+c}3\right)^3\ge4.$$Then approximately $a+b+c\ge2.4$ but we needed about $2.8$.

Comment: Here're some practice problems: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2998117_inspire_by_dragonheart6

Comment: @Math_fun2006 You may add more details of your attempt for possible reopening the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to prove that
$$2a + 2b + 2c - 3 \ge \sqrt 7.$$

Using $(a + b + c)^2 \ge a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ and $(a + b + c)^3/27 \ge abc$, we have
$(a + b + c)^2 + (a + b + c)^3/27 \ge 4$
which results in $a + b + c > 3/2$ or
$2a + 2b + 2c - 3 > 0$.

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$(2a + 2b + 2c - 3)^2 - 7 \ge 0.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &(2a + 2b + 2c - 3)^2 - 7 - 4(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + abc - 4)\\
 ={}& (-4ab + 8a + 8b - 12)c + 2(3-2a)(3-2b)\\
 \ge{}& 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
(*Note*: If $-4ab + 8a + 8b - 12 \ge 0 $, clearly (1) is true.
If $-4ab + 8a + 8b - 12 < 0$, we have
$(-4ab + 8a + 8b - 12)c + 2(3-2a)(3-2b)$
$\ge (-4ab + 8a + 8b - 12)\cdot \frac32 + 2(3-2a)(3-2b)$
$ = 2ab \ge 0$.)

We are done.

Comment: So it cannot reach equality, right?

Comment: @youthdoo With equality if $a = 3/2, c = 0$ (so $b = \sqrt{7}/2$).

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks!

Comment: @Math_fun2006 You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the inequality as  :

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-bc+\sqrt{b^2c^2-4\left(b+c\right)^{2}+8bc+16}\right)+b+c \geq \dfrac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2}$$

We make :

$$b+c=\operatorname{constant}=C$$

The function :

$$g(bc)=-bc+\sqrt{b^2c^2-4\left(C\right)^{2}+8bc+16}$$

Is increasing as $bc$ increases with $-bc+\sqrt{b^2c^2-4\left(C\right)^{2}+8bc+16}=a\geq 0$

So if $b=0$ with the constraint we have an equality as $c=1.5$

Done .

Comment: This method show also that $3$ is the maximum .

Answer (score 0):

Just to use Lagrange's multipliers to solve this one (as the OP commented Langrange cannot find the minimum in this problem): let $\mathrm L = a^2+b^2+c^2-\lambda\,abc$, then we have the equations to solve
$$2a=\lambda bc, 2b=\lambda ca, 2c=\lambda ab \implies a=b=c$$
and the constraint $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4 \implies a=b=c=1$ as the only  candidate point in the interior $a, b, c \in (0, \frac32)$ for a minimum, and here $\implies a+b+c=3^*$.

Checking for the boundaries, we must have at least one variable zero, so WLOG let $c=0 \implies a^2+b^2=4$, and we want to minimise $a+b$, gives $\{a,b\}=\{\frac32, \frac{\sqrt7}2\}$, which gives a value of $a+b=\frac{3+\sqrt7}2<3$, so clearly this gives the minimum.

--
$^*$ Note: it turns out we don't need to check if this point is actually a  minimum, as we have found a lower one subsequently.